# i get this error TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in python

Tags: python, json, tkinter

i try create a dictionary with json and python but i got this error
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

what should i do

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
import path
import json

data = path("json.json").()
word_list = json.loads(data)

from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
import path
import json

data = path("json.json").()
word_list = json.loads(data)

class root(Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.title('dictionery')
    self.minsize(380, 250)
    self.labels()
    self.dictionary()

  def labels(self):

    self.Label_1 = ttk.Label(self, text='serch')
    self.Label_1.grid(column=3, row= 0, padx= 55)  

    self.Entry_1 = Entry(self)
    self.Entry_1.grid(column=3 , row = 1, padx= 50)

    self.listBox = Listbox(self, height= 10, width= 40)
    self.listBox.grid(column=3, row= 3, padx= 60)

    self.button = ttk.Button(self, text= 'serch')
    self.button.place(x= 250, y=14)


  def dictionary(self):
    word = self.Entry_1.get()
    meanings =word_list[word]
    for meaning in meanings:
        self.listBox.insert(END, meaning)

window = root()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error traceback, which should also include the line number(s) in question. Also, your import statements and `data`/`word_list` are in here twice

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is caused by `import path`, which is invalid. What you probably actually want is `from pathlib import Path`

And the extra parentheses at the end of `data = path("json.json").()` are also a problem.

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk
from pathlib import Path  # import the 'Path' class from the 'pathlib' module
import json


file_path = Path(r'json.json')  # instantiate the 'Path' class here (capital "P")

with open(file_path, 'rb') as json_file:
    word_list = json.load(json_file)
```

Comment: i got this TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not WindowsPath

Comment: Updated - this should now properly load the contends of the JSON file for `word_list`